# Date Formation issues

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need your help -

In my project, I am using two languages English and Arabic, when I set device language to arabic then date formatter converts date into arabic format inside my app, but I want the date to be in English in both the versions whether device language is set to English or arabic , I want date to be in English format. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Comment: please post log & dateformatter code

Comment: try my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43841057/3901620

Comment: try my answer.....

Comment: @KKRocks you just need to add an answer. You don't also need to add a comment that you added an answer. Also, your answer is about NSNumberFormatter. Which is not related to NSDateFormatter.

Answer (score 0):

you have to explicitly set the dateformatters locale:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with setting NSLocale like below

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];
    NSDate* currentDate=[NSDate date];
    NSString * formattedDate=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
-(NSString *)formattedString:(NSString *)num{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar"]; // you can change here your local
     ///do your fromat here

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter2 = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    formatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en"];
    NSNumber *number2 = [formatter2 numberFromString:num];

    return [formatter stringFromNumber:number2];

}
```